# Best way to replace `None` values with 0 in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary -

```
{

    'buy': {'trade_transaction_amount__sum': None, 'tax__sum': None, 'trade_fee__sum': None}, 
    'sell': {'trade_transaction_amount__sum': None, 'tax__sum': None, 'trade_fee__sum': None}
}
```

What would be the best approach to replace the `None` values with `0`.

Note - Not every time the values for these keys are `None`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by they are not always None? Are they also an empty string '' or NaN? or sometimes they have a value?

Comment: They have an integer value or None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the recursive approach which works with any levels of nesting dictionaries :

```
d = {
    'buy': {'trade_transaction_amount__sum': None, 'tax__sum': None,
            'trade_fee__sum': None},
    'sell': {'trade_transaction_amount__sum': None, 'tax__sum': None,
             'trade_fee__sum': None}
}


def replacer(dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            replacer(v)

        elif v is None:
            dictionary[k] = 0


replacer(d)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use dictionary comprehension approach, and change the value to `0` if it returns a falsely value (such as `None`, `False`, `''` or `0`).

```py
d = {'a': None, 'b': 1}
d1 = {k: v or 0 for (k, v) in d.items()}
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively replace all `None` with `0` in the dict by checking the type of the values to see it's a nested `dict` or not.

```
test_dict = {
    'buy': {'trade_transaction_amount__sum': None, 'tax__sum': None, 'trade_fee__sum': None},
    'sell': {'trade_transaction_amount__sum': None, 'tax__sum': None, 'trade_fee__sum': None}
}

def replace_none_with(d, replacement=0):
    retval = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        if val is None:
            retval[key] = replacement
        elif isinstance(val, dict):
            retval[key] = replace_none_with(val, replacement)
        else:
            retval[key] = val
    return retval

print(replace_none_with(test_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'buy': {'trade_transaction_amount__sum': 0, 'tax__sum': 0, 'trade_fee__sum': 0}, 'sell': {'trade_transaction_amount__sum': 0, 'tax__sum': 0, 'trade_fee__sum': 0}}
```